# Android AsyncTask/doInBackground pattern

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, design-patterns, android-asynctask

This is more a "how should I design" than a "how do I code" so I hope this is in the right place...

I've got a pretty standard class that extends from AsyncTask.

How do I best lay this out to do many different tasks? For example working with GAE I have standard get, insert, delete, update methods that all need to run asynchronously.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    if (tipApiService == null) {
        TipBeanApi.Builder builder = new TipBeanApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)

                .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/").setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                    @Override
                    public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                        abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                    }
                });

        tipApiService = builder.build();
    }

    try {
        tipApiService.insert(tip).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "pushToRemote: " + e.toString());
    }

    return null;
}
```

You can see in the try block I execute the insert method.

What if I wanted to do something else instead? Should I create a entire new class for each operation, or pass a condition statement in that dictates what should be done? Is there another cleaner/better way that I just don't know about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been working on an Android app for the past few months that uses GAE and Google Cloud endpoints, so hopefully my approach will help you out.

In my Application class is where I build all my endpoints, so for you it will look something like this:

```
public class ThisApp extends Application {

    private static TipBeanApi tipApiService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        buildCloudEndpoints();
    }

    private void buildCloudEndpoints() {
        TipBeanApi.Builder builder = new TipBeanApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
        new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
            .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/").setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {@Override
            public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest <? > abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
            }
        });

        tipApiService = builder.build();
    }

    public static TipBeanApi getApiService() {
        return tipApiService;
    }

}
```

Now anywhere, in your app you can just do `ThisApp.getApiService().yourEndpoint().execute();` to execute an endpoint call.

Finally, I recommend making all the AsyncTasks as embedded classes, so that you're not creating a new java file for every single API call you wish to make. A good rule of thumb is that if you only call the API once in your app, then just embed the AsyncTask in the Activity which calls it e.g. `private class YourApiCallTask extends AsyncTask ...` otherwise if you call it multiple times, then you should create a class called "ApiServiceEndpoints" and use it to hold all your API call tasks e.g. `public static class YourApiCallTask extends AsyncTask ...` If you have say less than 10 or so endpoints, then you can just stick all the AsyncTasks in your ApiServiceEndpoints class, and your activities' code will be a lot cleaner.

I hope this helps, and don't hesitate to ask any more questions about using GAE/cloud endpoints with an Android app!

Comment: Thanks for the idea of moving endpoints, makes perfect sense. Just so I'm clear though, you're still creating a new AsyncTask class for each action? Obviously that class can be smaller now and be a inner class, but still seems unnecessary/feels dirty. I feel like i'm going to end up with a switch statement in the constructor (ugh)... perhaps a factory style pattern would be a better approach?

Comment: Yes, I'm creating a new AsyncTask for each Endpoint call, and there's a couple reasons why. First, different API calls for me have different responses, so processing the response (or error handling) can be encapsulated in it's own doInBackground() method. Second, each task has a onPostExecute() method you can override, which runs on the UI thread, allowing you to update your UI with any new data from the response. If you have common response handling, feel free to compress into one task. Using a factory to get instances of the tasks is a good idea too! If this helps, please accept/upvote :)